# Ajax post to Python cgi script

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, cgi

I am trying to use  Ajax to post value to a Python cgi.
I had a couple of years ago these test JS and Python scripts working, but now I cannot get them to work.

When I post the a JSON to the cgi, it get Status code: 200 OK. But the response: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse unexpected end of data at line  column 1 of the JSON"

Any idea of what I am doing wrong:

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Ajax POST</h1>
    <form id="postform">
      <input type="text" name="myquery" id="query" />
    </form>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!">
    <p id="response"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$('input#submit').click(
    function(){
        var formVal= $("#query").val();
        console.log(JSON.stringify({'myquery': formVal}));

        //Ajax POST
        $.ajax({
            contentType:"application/json",
            type: "POST",
            data:JSON.stringify({'myquery': formVal}),
            dataType:"json",
            url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/test_ajax.cgi", //the url ofthe cgiscrip\
            success: function(data){
                console.log('success');
                if(data){
                    console.log(data.success, data.msg);
                    $('p#response').text(data.msg)
                }

            }
        })

    }
)
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Python CGI:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import cgi, os, json, sys

method = os.environ.get("REQUEST_METHOD")

result = {'success':'true', 'msg': " was posted by you"}
print "Content-type: application/json\n\n"
print json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: The jQuery ajax option `dataType: "json"` assumes json is going to be returned but in your CGI script you print both `"Content-type: application/json\n\n"` and then the actual JSON (`json.dumps(result)`). Are you sure the `Content-Type` header is supposed to be set this way? It looks like jQuery is trying to parse JSON from `Content-type: application/json\n\n` and fails.

Comment: If I leave `Content-type: application/json\n\n` out I get an "Internal Server Error" 500

Comment: Then instead could you specify the `dataType` as `"text"` and `console.log` the `data` returned in the callback? Then you could clearly see if the format is valid JSON.